# node js - how to modify an existing job in agenda

Tags: node.js, agenda

I am creating a back-end application using node js and mongoDb and in that i am using [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) for job scheduling. I have offerModel in my application to add, update or delete offers. So, for updating the expired offers according to their validity, i am using job scheduling library [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda). Now if i am increasing the offer's validity, do i need to delete the corresponding job and again define it, or Is there a way to update an existing job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't update the entry. You need to cancel and define the entry like:

```
agenda.cancel({name: jobName}, function(err, numRemoved) {
    var jobName = 'job' + new Date().getTime();

    agenda.define(jobName, doSomething);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest updated docs, we can use `agenda.unique` API to update existing job. As an example -

```
agenda
    .create("Job_Name", data_to_be_updated)
    .repeatEvery(schedule)
    .unique({ "data.unique_id": data_to_be_updated.unique_id })
    .save();
```

The above example creates a repetitive job which will update the `data` of the same job. I have included the `repeatEvery` API in the example as in most of the cases, repeating jobs are supposed to be updated & kept unique.

Reference - [Agenda API Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda#uniqueproperties-options)

I hope this helps.